# Regular expression for 0 or a positive number

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression to check that a string's value is either a '0', or a positive number with a length equal to 1 to 10 (also where the first digit cannot be zero).

I'm stuck, I can get the 0, but I can't get the positive number.

Here is what I have:

```
(^([0])$)|(^([1-9][0-9]{0-9})$)
```

This reg exp looks a little crazy, I've been trying a lot of different things and making even more crazier and crazier.

Comment: Wouldn't casting to an int be faster and easier?

Comment: why not try to just parse it and ignore regex?

Comment: Are you trying to validate, or extract text?

Comment: Nice to see you posting a question asking a clear regex question, making a good effort to actually solve it yourself, and showing that you mostly understand what's going on. For regexes, that's the exception, not the norm, unfortunately, so I just want to say keep this up. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a range of possibilities, you use a comma, not a hyphen.

```
(^([0])$)|(^([1-9][0-9]{0,9})$)
```

However, your regex can be shortened to:

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]{0,9})$
```

Answer (score 3):

offering the faster, non-Regex approach:

```
static void Main(string[] args
{
     string str = "12";

     long test;
     if(str.Length <= 10 
         && long.TryParse(str, out test)
         && test >= 0)
     {
        //valid   
     }
}
```